# Is it possible to inject JavaScript code in a page embedded by IFRAME tag?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, click

There is a certain page (say, named "TargetPage.html" in which I inject the Javascript code below by means of a Firefox extension:

```
<!-- TargetPage.html -->
unsafeWindow.document.getElementById("target-element").click();
```

I want to embed this page into another page (say, named "AnotherPage.php") by using the HTML tag "iframe". Like below:

```
<!-- AnotherPage.php -->
<iframe src="TargetPage.html"></iframe>
```

Now that I embedded it via "iframe", there is no way to inject any JavaScript code with a browser extension.

Is there any way of running this code in the embedded page?

Comment: You're trying to go deeper than the guys from **Inception**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if both pages are in the same domain.

Otherwise is considered cross-domain scripts, and it's a big no-no, for browsers to allow it.

However, there are ways to achieve such communication between domains.